# Swift vapor POST gives response but doesn't save

Tags: swift, postgresql, post, get, vapor

So, I'm trying out Vapor and, so far, it's simple [This guide](https://medium.com/flatiron-labs/persisting-data-with-vapor-3-and-postgresql-246386ac1448).

There was actually only one thing that was outdated:

`migrations.add(model: User.self, database: DatabaseIdentifier<User.Database>.psql)`

is required instead of:

`databases.add(database: postgres, as: .psql)`

Then I tested to add a row manually as described in the guide. Made a GET request and I got the response nice and clean as it should look.

Then I was going to do a POST and I thought everything worked fine since I got the model in response when making the POST-request.

I noticed though, after making another GET request, nothing was saved. I know there are a lot of areas in code to cover, but in general, anyone know what I'm missing?

```swift
router.post("user", use: userController.create)
func create(_ req: Request) throws -> Future<User> {
    return try req.content.decode(User.self).flatMap { user in
        return user.save(on: req)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `create` instead of `save`?

Comment: @imike Thank you that worked. Altho the documentation for save says that it first try to create and if the id already exist it runs update instead.. guess that is wrong then.

Comment: Also it is time to use Vapor 4, so if you're in the very beginning then it'd be better to switch cause Vapor3 is too old already  if you need any help with Vapor please don't hesitate to write me in Discord to `iMike#3049` 